# clang-format not working under gVim

Tags: c++, vim, clang, clang-format

I installed `clang-format-3.8` via apt-get.
Now I try to use it in gVim, but it is not working.
I checked and clang-format-3.8 exists in the folder `/usr/share/vim/addons/syntax`.

But when I enter `:pyf /usr/share/vim/addons/syntax/clang-format-3.8.py` in my vim command line, it returns:

`E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version`.

I use gVim 7.4 under Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Vim in Ubuntu is compiled with Python 3 instead of Python 2. You need to compile your own vim with Python 2 to get that plug in work

Comment: `s/:pyf/:py3f/` works for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Vim binary shipped with Ubuntu 16.04 is compiled with Python 3. The vim addons of clang-format is written by Python 2.

You need to either:

- write your own addon by Python 3
- Compile your own vim with Python 2, which is the easiest way

The instructions to build vim with Python can be found by Google.

Comment: I expect I'm not the only one with this problem, as I don't want to compile with py2 (I'm pretty sure this will bring up new conflicts with other plugins), are there any addons for Python 3? I can't find any that work

Comment: Check your vimrc first. In my case, there're no conflict when switch to Python 2. Unfortunately, afaik, there is no available add on yet. Make it yourself

Answer (score 18):

Dahn's answer is correct that the Vim binary that ships with Ubuntu 16.04 is compiled with Python 3 rather than Python 2.  The `clang-format-3.8.py` script in the Ubuntu 16.04 `clang-format-3.8` package is not compatible with Python 3.

But the latest `clang-format.py` *does* work with Python 3.  You can get it here:

https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/tools/clang-format/clang-format.py

I think it was just a matter of putting parentheses around the `print` statements.

Save this file somewhere on your computer such as `/usr/local/share/vim/addons/syntax/`.

This script uses `clang-format` as the binary name, so you'll want to install the `clang-format` package, which installs the `clang-format` command as a symlink to `clang-format-3.8`.

Since Vim is now loading a Python 3 script, replace your `:pyf` (not available) command with `:py3f`:

`:py3f /usr/local/share/vim/addons/syntax/clang-format.py`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I installed `clang-format` via apt-get. It created a `clang-format.py` file in my chosen path: `/usr/share/vim/addons/syntax`. I overwrote it with the one from the link and tried it on gvim with `:pyf3 /usr/share/vim/addons/syntax/clang-format.py`. It did not work and gave me the message `Not an editor command ...`. What did I do wrong?

Comment: My mistake.  It should be `:py3f`, not `:pyf3`.  Editing my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Also, be careful about deciding to save/install anything under `/usr` outside of `/usr/local`:

http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/introduction/position.html

If you save it in `/usr` outside of `/usr/local`, your freshly-downloaded `clang-format.py` could be overwritten by the distribution when you upgrade.

Comment: clang-format-4.0 seems to be shipping with a python 3 version of clang-format.py, so my vim config for binding control+k to format the line was as simple as `map <C-K> :py3f /usr/share/clang/clang-format-4.0/clang-format.py<cr>`

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the above answers I had to do a few more things. I downloaded a new python file and changed the key mapping recommended by in the clang python file to the following in my .vimrc:

```
    map <C-I> :py3file <path-to-this-file>/clang-format.py<cr>
    imap <C-I> <c-o>:py3file <path-to-this-file>/clang-format.py<cr>
```

This solved the E319 problem I was getting.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem differently using a combination of `bash` and `vim` commands.

First, I installed `clang-format` package

```
# apt-get install clang-format-3.5
```

(I choose version 3.5 but you can choose a different one)

Second, Test if `clang-format` is working

```
$ clang-format-3.5 -style=Google  test.cpp
```

Then, run `vim`

```
$ vim test.cpp
```

`vim` allows to run an external command and print it's output into current buffer

```
:r ! clang-format-3.5 -style=Google  %
```

(more details about external commands in vim https://www.linux.com/learn/vim-tips-working-external-commands)

This will append the output of `clang-format` into current buffer. To replace current buffer, which is the desirable effect, specify the lines to output into

```
:%! clang-format-3.5 -style=Google  %
```

(the first `%` means all line in current file)

You can make this process more productive by defining new commands in vim (using `command`) for both visual and command-line modes.